# Regex Expression in Java for Upper case Greek letter

Tags: java

I want to validate a string to accept only greek capital letter.
I have tried using regex expression as below:

```
 var stringPattern = "^\\p{InGreek}{7}"
```

This works for both upper and lower case, but I need to validate and allow only upper case greek letters.
Can someone guide me on the same??
Thanks

Comment: `var stringPattern` is not java syntax.

Comment: Is this C# or JavaScript? or do you want to accomplish the task in Java?

Comment: @Kaushal28 Isn't this feature added in Java 9?

Comment: Yes . I am currently programming in Gosu. But any suggestion on valid expression for my requirement in Java would also would be of great help.

Comment: There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404733/java-how-to-check-if-character-belongs-to-a-specific-unicode-block). It might help you.

Comment: @Sweeper I don't think so.  Oracle originally intended to include `var` in Java 9 but my understanding is that they ended up not doing so.  I don't know why not.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that the upper case Greek letters occur contiguously in Unicode space, and simply write `"[Α-Ω]{7}"` - note that the first character there is a capital alpha, not an ASCII A.  Or to make it even clearer, write `"[\u0391-\u03A9]{7}"`.