# How do I use a Ruby regex to capture non-English words?

Tags: ruby, regex, utf-8, cpu-word

I am trying to validate 'words' with Ruby 1.8.7.

My regex to catch a word is currently:

```
/[a-zA-Z]\'*\-*/
```

This will only catch English words; Is there a way to catch non-English UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Try using \w instead of [a-zA-Z]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397788/why-does-w-match-only-english-words-in-javascript-regex

Comment: @Geek. Good point, `/\w+/` is right, but he also needs `/\w+/u`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the 1.8.x Regex engine is UTF-8 aware, you just need to use the right expression, and it's slightly more than just using `/\w/`:

```
s = "résumé and some other words"
puts s[/[a-z]+/u]
puts s[/\w+/u]
```

and you get:

```
r
résumé
```