# regular expression with hebrew or english

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, hebrew

I'm looking for a pattern that accept only hebrew or english letters from 2 letters to 15, and can accept 1 space.  I have tried following code but it does not matching my string:

```
<?php
$subject = "שלום לך";
$regexp="#^\p[{Hebrew}| ][a-zA-Z]{2,15}? \+$#u";
print_r(preg_match($regexp, $subject));
?>
```

Comment: Note - similar regular expression can be used in other dialects of regular expression, i.e. for C#/.Net is [IsHebrew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) instead.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple errors in your code.

First, your regex

```
$regexp="#^\p[{Hebrew}| ][a-zA-Z]{2,15}? \+$#u";
```

Here is what it means:

```
#                     : regex delimiter
  ^                   : begining of string
    \p                : character p
    [{Hebrew}| ]      : character class, one of the char : {, H, e, b, r, w, }, |, space 
    [a-zA-Z]{2,15}?   : from 2 to 15 alphabetic char
     \+               : a space followed by +
  $                   : end of string
#                     : regex delimiter
u                     : unicode
```

Unicode hebrew char is : `\p{Hebrew}`
there no needs of `|` inside a char class
there is no `+` in your string, no space at the end
there no need to do ungreedy matching

so it sould be rewritten as:

```
$regexp="#^[\p{Hebrew} a-zA-Z]{2,15}$#u";
```

**explanation:**

```
#                 : regex delimiter
  ^               : begining of string
    [             : start class character
      \p{Hebrew}  : a hebrew character
                  : a space
      a-zA-Z      : a latin letter
    ]             : end of class
    {2,15}        : previous chars 2 to 15 times
  $               : end of string
#                 : regex delimiter
u                 : unicode
```

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) doesn't return an array but an int that holds the number of time the pattern is found in the string.

Then your script becomes:

```
$subject = "שלום לך";
$regexp  = "#^[\p{Hebrew} a-zA-Z]{2,15}$#u";
preg_match($regexp, $subject, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397788/why-does-w-match-only-english-words-in-javascript-regex)? Dose that work for you?

```
[\w\u0590-\u05FF]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var regexp = /^[\u0591-\u05F4\s]+$/gi;
return regexp.test(str)
```