# Regex for Hebrew and symbols

Tags: c#, regex, hebrew

I need an expression that can accept only Hebrew letters and at least one space char.

I tried this for Hebrew letters, but it doesn't match sentences with Hebrew text and spaces:

```
result = Regex.IsMatch(txtName.Text, @"[\u05D0\u05D1\u05D2\u05D3\u05D4\u05D5\u05D6\u05D7\u05D8\u05D9\u05DA\u05DB\u05DC\u05DD\u05DE\u05DF\u05E0\u05E1\u05E2\u05E3\u05E4\u05E5\u05E6\u05E7\u05E8\u05E9\u05EA]");
```

How can I represent all the Hebrew letters and at least one space char in regEx?

Comment: Did you try anything? A small suggestion: if you tried anything...post it, you won't be downvoted! Hebrew characters UNICODE range is from `0x0590` to `0x05ff`, spaces may be represented by `\s` and with `+` you'll require one or more of them...this regex should match it: `[\u0590-\u05ff]+\s+`

Comment: Side note: "tried a lot" is not really showing any effort. Even single sample line of code showing what you've actually tried would likely avoid all downwotes. Same goes "searched a lot" if you ever decide to add that to your posts - show your search query/best result you found and it is clear what is wrong (for all people would know you are searching on http://dinsney.com).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9242066/1043380

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - question looks real now - consider posting your comment as answer, also gunr2171 suggestion shows much better approach - should be duplicate (but I've used up my vote already :) )

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I tried what you suggest, it works only if I have one word. If I enter a sentence to check and the other words in english the flag dosent 'rise up'..How to fix it that will work for many words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for expression similar to `@"[\p{IsHebrew} ]+"` - at least one character either Hebrew or space. To match whole sentence - add begin/end anchors - `@"^[\p{IsHebrew} ]+$"`.

For detailed explanation see [regular expression with hebrew or english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197003/regular-expression-with-hebrew-or-english/9242066#9242066) and [C#/.Net Character Classes in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories).

Comment: +1 for `\p{IsHebrew}`, I should remember to keep an eye on every question tagged [regex], there is always something new to learn...