# Space validation in full name field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to place check in Full name field that full name field should accept space between first and last name using i am using `strrpos()` function for it but not working

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex...

```
if (preg_match("/(.+)( )(.+)/", $full_name))
{ 
// returns true if name is formed of two words with a space between
}
```

For even better validation, you can use \w although keep in mind that it will only match English word characters.  See here for more info: [Why does \w match only English words in javascript regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397788/why-does-w-match-only-english-words-in-javascript-regex#397801)

```
preg_match("/(\w+)( )(\w+)/", $full_name)
```

Comment: If it's names, why not `/(w+)( )(w+)/` to add some extra validation

Comment: That works as well.  I'll update my answer, but also keep in mind that if the user is attempting to match non-english characters, I don't believe \w will work.